# How to speed up SELECT .. LIKE queries in MySQL on multiple columns?

Tags: mysql, sql-like

I have a MySQL table for which I do very frequent `SELECT x, y, z FROM table WHERE x LIKE '%text%' OR y LIKE '%text%' OR z LIKE '%text%'` queries. Would any kind of index help speed things up?

There are a few million records in the table. If there is anything that would speed up the search, would it seriously impact disk usage by the database files and the speed of `INSERT` and `DELETE` statements? (no `UPDATE` is ever performed)

**Update**: Quickly after posting, I have seen a lot of information and discussion about the way `LIKE` is used in the query; I would like to point out that the solution **must** use `LIKE '%text%'` (that is, the text I am looking for is prepended and appended with a % wildcard). The database also has to be local, for many reasons, including security.

Comment: Think of it this way it is not a perfect analogy, but it demonstrates the point. Consider a book with a word index at the back. If you want to look up a simple word or even words that start with the same first few letters, no problem. Consider what happens when you want to use that book index to look up all words that contain the letters "exe" anywhere in the word. The index is pretty much useless and you might as well read the actual book looking for those words. That's roughly the problem you are imposing on mySQL.

Answer (score 85, accepted):

An index wouldn't speed up the query, because for textual columns indexes work by indexing N characters starting from left. When you do LIKE '%text%' it can't use the index because there can be a variable number of characters before text.

What you should be doing is not use a query like that at all. Instead you should use something like FTS (Full Text Search) that MySQL supports for MyISAM tables. It's also pretty easy to make such indexing system yourself for non-MyISAM tables, you just need a separate index table where you store words and their relevant IDs in the actual table.

**Update**

Full text search available for InnoDB tables with MySQL 5.6+.

Comment: I should add that since MySQL 5.6, full text search is also available for InnoDB.

Comment: There are some cases where a full-text search isn't possible though, like with ideographic languages. https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/fulltext-restrictions.html

Comment: Note that `FULLTEXT` also lets you do all 3 tests at once:  `MATCH(x, y, z) AGAINST('text')`.

Comment: full text search uses word boundary and not wildcard saerch

Comment: I don't understand why this answer is accepted as the provided soultions is not what the OP asked for, it must work same as `%string%` and full-text doesn't do wildcard like search

Answer (score 32):

An index won't help text matching with a leading wildcard, an index can be used for:

```
LIKE 'text%'
```

But I'm guessing that won't cut it. For this type of query you really should be looking at a full text search provider if you want to scale the amount of records you can search across. My preferred provider is [Sphinx](http://www.sphinxsearch.com/), very full featured/fast etc. [Lucene](http://lucene.apache.org/java/docs/) might also be worth a look. A fulltext index on a MyISAM table will also work, but ultimately pursuing MyISAM for any database that has a significant amount of writes isn't a good idea.

Comment: In MySQL 5.6 and up, they can also be used with InnoDB tables. https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/fulltext-restrictions.html

Answer (score 25):

### Add a Full Text Index and Use `MATCH() AGAINST()`.

Normal indexes will not help you with `like` queries, especially those that utilize wildcards on both sides of the search term.

What you can do is add a full text index on the columns that you're interested in searching and then use a `MATCH() AGAINST()` query to search those full text indexes.

1. Add a full text index on the columns that you need:

   ```
   ALTER TABLE table ADD FULLTEXT INDEX index_table_on_x_y_z (x, y, z);
   ```
2. Then query those columns:

   ```
   SELECT * FROM table WHERE MATCH(x,y,z) AGAINST("text")
   ```

From our trials, we found these queries to take around 1ms in a table with over 1 million records. Not bad, especially compared to the equivalent wildcard `LIKE %text%` query which takes 16,400ms.

#### Benchmarks

`MATCH(x,y,z) AGAINST("text")` takes 1ms

`LIKE %text%` takes 16400ms

**16400x faster!**

Comment: You didn't mention that MATCH, AGAINST is not the same as like wildcard !
it's like a where "=", more performant.

Comment: @Dev'Hamz You sure about that?

Comment: Yes I tested it

Comment: When you use index, the more powerful way I found is to use like 'text%'

Comment: Interesting. In our tests, using `MATCH(x,y,z) AGAINST("text")` gave us the same results returned as `LIKE %text%` except it uses the `FULLTEXT` index so it's way faster. Doesn't `MATCH AGAINST` not inherently use a wildcard or am I missing something?

Comment: @JoshuaPinter It wont find a row with 'I am texting message'  string in it. so No, full-text and like wild-card are not same

Answer (score 23):

An index can **not** be used to speed up queries where the search criteria starts with a wildcard:

`LIKE '%text%'`

An index can (and might be, depending on selectivity) used for search terms of the form:

`LIKE 'text%'`

Answer (score 12):

I would add that in some cases you can speed up the query using an index together with like/rlike if the field you are looking at is often empty or contains something constant.

In that case it seems that you can limit the rows which are visited using the index by adding an "and" clause with the fixed value.

I tried this for searching 'tags' in a huge table which usually does not contain a lot of tags.

`SELECT * FROM objects WHERE tags RLIKE("((^|,)tag(,|$))" AND tags!=''`

If you have an index on tags you will see that it is used to limit the rows which are being searched.

Comment: This is surprisingly a very good alternative, I was able to index the column this way.

Comment: Better:  `RLIKE '[[:<:]]tag[[:>:]]'` -- that is, use "word boundaries".

Comment: @RickJames This was nott about the regular expression but about adding the AND to the query. Besides this, the regular expression used depends on the data. If your tags contain spaces you won't be happy with word boundaries. I am also not sure if searching word boundaries instead a small set of delimiters will be faster on a microbenchmark level.

Comment: @OderWat - A small test:  `SELECT "What about this?" REGEXP "[[:<:]]about this[[:>:]]";` says `1` (true).

Comment: @RickJames of course this is true. But using word delimiter is still not practical for searching tags from a field. Think of: `SELECT "white lion steak,lion steak,white" REGEXP "[[:<:]]white lion[[:>:]]"`. This is true too, but should probably not. It all depends on how your data is stored.

Answer (score 6):

Maybe you can try to upgrade mysql5.1 to mysql5.7.

I have about 70,000 records. And run following SQL:

```
select * from comics where name like '%test%';
```

It takes **2000ms** in mysql5.1.
And it takes **200ms** in mysql5.7 or mysql5.6.

Comment: That really smells as if not all the data was cached in the buffer_pool on 5.1.  10:1 is a typical factor.  And nothing in this area changed from 5.1 to 5.6.

Answer (score 4):

Another way:

You can mantain calculated columns with those strings REVERSEd and use

```
SELECT x, y, z FROM table WHERE x LIKE 'text%' OR y LIKE 'text%' OR z LIKE 'text%' OR xRev LIKE 'txet%' OR yRev LIKE 'txet%' OR zRev LIKE 'txet%'
```

Example of how to ADD a stored persisted column

```
ALTER TABLE table ADD COLUMN xRev VARCHAR(N) GENERATED ALWAYS AS REVERSE(x) stored;
```

and then create an indexes on `xRev`, `yRev` etc.

Comment: yes but thats not inner wildcard searc %s%

Answer (score 0):

Another alternative to avoid full table scans is selecting substrings and checking them in the having statement:

```
SELECT 
    al3.article_number,
    SUBSTR(al3.article_number, 2, 3) AS art_nr_substr,
    SUBSTR(al3.article_number, 1, 3) AS art_nr_substr2,
    al1.*
FROM
    t1 al1 
    INNER JOIN t2 al2 ON al2.t1_id = al1.id
    INNER JOIN t3 al3 ON al3.id = al2.t3_id
WHERE
    al1.created_at > '2018-05-29'
HAVING 
    (art_nr_substr = "FLA" OR art_nr_substr = 'VKV' OR art_nr_subst2 = 'PBR');
```

Comment: No.  The real cost is needing to look at lots of rows.  You have not changed the number of rows.

Comment: Substrings are not indexed

Answer (score 0):

When you optimize a `SELECT foo FROM bar WHERE baz LIKE 'ZOT%'` query, you want the index length to at least match the number of characters in the request.

Here is a real life example from just now:

Here is the query:

```sql
EXPLAIN SELECT COUNT(*) FROM client_detail cd
JOIN client_account ca ON cd.client_acct_id = ca.client_acct_id
WHERE cd.first_name LIKE 'XX%' AND cd.last_name_index LIKE 'YY%';
```

With no index:

```
+-------+
| rows  |
+-------+
| 13994 |
|     1 |
+-------+
```

So first try a 4x index,

```sql
CREATE INDEX idx_last_first_4x4 on client_detail(last_name_index(4), first_name(4));
```

```
+------+
| rows |
+------+
| 7035 |
|    1 |
+------+
```

A bit better, but COUNT(*) shows there are only 102 results.  So lets now add a 2x index:

```sql
CREATE INDEX idx_last_first_2x2 on client_detail(last_name_index(2), first_name(2));
```

yields:

```
+------+
| rows |
+------+
|  102 |
|    1 |
+------+
```

Both indexes are still in place at this point, and MySQL chose the latter index for this query---however it will still choose the 4x4 query if it is more efficient.

Index ordering may be useful, try the 2x2 before the 4x4 or vice-versa to see how it performs for your environment. To re-order an index you have to drop and re-create the earlier one.