# Ruby on rails, the ways to speed up search in database

Tags: ruby-on-rails, database-performance, sqlite3-ruby

I have the table products with following fields:
code - string,
id - integer

My table has over 5 million rows.

In the model I use code:

```
find(:all, :conditions => ['code = ?', "#{search}"])
```

It takes 2 seconds to find the result.
Is there any way to reduce search time?

I'm using rails 3.2.11, ruby 1.9.3 and sqlite3 as db

**UPD**
Changed model code

Comment: What is your DB engine ? On mySQL you have the FULLTEXT search on TEXT fields.

Comment: Maybe this can help:
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2042269/how-to-speed-up-select-like-queries-in-mysql-on-multiple-columns

Comment: Changed my model code - I do not need FTS.

Answer (score 0):

I've managed to find answer.
Just added

```
add_index :products, :code
```

to migration change and now it works really fast. 
You will find more information [here](https://tomafro.net/2009/08/using-indexes-in-rails-index-your-associations)