# Grouping multiple like statements

Tags: php, mysql

I'm new to SQL can't seem to group multiple `LIKE` statements together. Any idea what I am doing incorrectly?

```
$query = mysqli_query($mysqli, "SELECT * FROM table_name
            WHERE Page LIKE ".$page."
            AND Profession LIKE ".$profession.", 
            AND Age LIKE ".$age."");
```

Thanks.

Comment: What is going wrong? Do you have an error or do you have wrong result?

Comment: use single quotes '.$page.' '.$profession.' '.$age.'

Comment: When using `mysqli` you should be using parameterized queries and [`bind_param`](http://php.net/manual/en/mysqli-stmt.bind-param.php) to add user data to your query. **DO NOT** use string interpolation to accomplish this because you will create severe [SQL injection bugs](http://bobby-tables.com/). You shouldn't have to concern yourself with quoting issues.

Comment: what's the point of using mysqli when you create your query like that,  without bindings.

Comment: you should not use comma after and so remove comma after '$profession.'

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Its likely because they are not enclosed correctly

```
$query = mysqli_query($mysqli, "SELECT * FROM table_name
            WHERE Page LIKE ".$page."
            AND Profession LIKE ".$profession."
            AND Age LIKE ".$age."");
```

when compiled is something like

```
SELECT * FROM table_name
            WHERE Page LIKE page number 1
            AND Profession LIKE my profession
            AND Age LIKE 100
```

which is invalid SQL

You need to use quotes and escape the values

```
$query = mysqli_query($mysqli, "SELECT * FROM table_name
            WHERE Page LIKE '%".$page."%'
            AND Profession LIKE '%".$profession."%'
            AND Age LIKE '%".$age."%'");
```

would give

```
SELECT * FROM table_name
            WHERE Page LIKE '%page number 1%'
            AND Profession LIKE '%my profession%'
            AND Age LIKE '%100%'
```

Which will likely give a result of what you would expect

Make sure the values are safe though by at bare minimum using http://www.php.net/manual/en/mysqli.real-escape-string.php though looking at prepared statements would be a better option

**Edit:**

Remove comma after `LIKE ". $profession."`

Comment: Works great, but appears to be very slow. It takes about 2 seconds to query a 10 row column.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2042269/how-to-speed-up-select-like-queries-in-mysql-on-multiple-columns

Answer (score 0):

This would be a lot easier to get right if you use placeholders and [`bind_param`](http://www.php.net/manual/en/mysqli-stmt.bind-param.php):

```
$stmt = mysqli_query($mysqli, "SELECT * FROM table_name
            WHERE Page LIKE ?
            AND Profession LIKE ?
            AND Age=?");

mysqli_stmt_bind_param($stmt, 'ssi', "%" . $page . "%", "%" . $profession. "%", $age);

mysqli_stmt_execute($stmt);
```