# How to make my PHP code more efficient for a search database?

Tags: php, mysql, search, phpmyadmin

Main objective for this post is to open up a can of worms. I would like to get some advise on what is the best way/ most efficient way to search a phpmyadmin database.

I am just starting to learn PHP. Main goal is to be able to write my own search databases as that has always interested me. I played around with some code to build a basic search database and have it working now.

Below is the code I used. I would guess as it is my first attempt at this I am going about it the wrong way. Assuming this was a large database, how could I make this more efficient? Am I going about it the wrong way using PHP? Is there a better way to do this?

The goal is to have searchable database where the user has multiple options to query to help refine the results.

```html
<html>
<head>
<title> test Search </title>
<style type="text/css">

table {
 background-color: #ffffff;
}

th {
 width: 200px;
 text-align: left;
}

</style>
</head>
<body>
<h1> test Search</h1>


<form method="post" action="index.php">
<input type="hidden" name="submitted" value="true"/>

<label>Colour 1: <input type="text" name="criteria" /></label>

<label>Colour 2: <input type="text" name="criteria2" /></label>

<label>PostCode: <input type="text" name="criteria3" /></label>

<label>Suburb: <input type="text" name="criteria4" /></label>

<label>State: <input type="text" name="criteria5" /></label>
<input type="submit" />


</form>

<?php 

if (isset($_POST['submitted'])) {

// connect to the database

include('connect.php');
//echo "connected " ;
$criteria = $_POST['criteria'];
$criteria2 = $_POST['criteria2'];
$criteria3 = $_POST['criteria3'];
$criteria4 = $_POST['criteria4'];
$criteria5 = $_POST['criteria5'];

$query = "SELECT * FROM `Mainlist` WHERE (`Colour1`like '%$criteria%') and (`Colour2`like '%$criteria2%') 
and (`PostCode`like '%$criteria3%') and (`Suburb`like '%$criteria4%') and (`State`like '%$criteria5%')



LIMIT 0,10";
$result = mysqli_query($dbcon, $query) or die(' but there was an error getting data');

echo "<table>";

echo "<tr> <th>School</th> <th>State</th> <th>Suburb</th> <th>PostCode</th> <th>Logo</th> <th>Uniform</th></tr>";

while ($row = mysqli_fetch_array($result, MYSQLI_ASSOC)) {

 echo "<tr><td>";
 echo $row['School'];
 echo "</td><td>";
 echo $row['State'];
 echo "</td><td>";
 echo $row['Suburb'];
 echo "</td><td>";
 echo $row['PostCode'];
 echo "</td><td><img src=\"data:image/jpeg;base64,";
 echo base64_encode($row['Logo']);
 echo "\" /></td></td>";
 echo "</td><td><img src=\"data:image/jpeg;base64,";
 echo base64_encode($row['Uniform']);
 echo "\" /></td></td>";
 
 }

echo "</table>";



}// end of main if statment

?>


</body>
</html>
```

Comment: This is more a code review question rather than a specific code-based problem and is thus unlikely to get a satisfactory answer. Instead head to https://codereview.stackexchange.com/

Comment: ok thanks, I will post over there.

Comment: You might also want to brush up on the terminology, there is no such thing as a phpmyadmin database, but a `mysql` database, phpmyadmin is just some php frontend.

Comment: Note that LIMIT without ORDER BY is fairly meaningless

Comment: But the slowness is those likes, or, more specifically, those '%...' strings- which cannot use an index even if one were available

Comment: I disagree with the first comment incidentally

Comment: Thanks Strawberry, I added Order by to the code. I don't understand your comment about the %. I will Google it to see if I can make sense of that. Are you saying I should remove the % from `Colour1`like '%$criteria%'

and just have `Colour1`like '$criteria'

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2042269/how-to-speed-up-select-like-queries-in-mysql-on-multiple-columns . Can't put non-escaped data into a query string. Also this https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/string-comparison-functions.html about non-escaped `%_` in LIKE.

Comment: ok thanks, I have removed % from the criteria as there is no reason for them to be like that. I read the other posts Deadooshka, thanks for that.