# Laravel trying to query multiple tables

Tags: php, mysql, laravel

Not quite sure how to fix this and if this even is an issue with my query or database, so here it goes. There are 3 tables, products, relations and tags.

```
'products' (
    'ID' bigint(20) unsigned NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
    'user_id' bigint(20) unsigned NOT NULL,
    'name' varchar(200) COLLATE utf8mb4_unicode_ci DEFAULT NULL,
    'primary_image' bigint(20) DEFAULT NULL,
    'description' longtext COLLATE utf8mb4_unicode_ci,
    'price' float DEFAULT NULL,
    'sale_price' float DEFAULT NULL,
    'currency' varchar(25) COLLATE utf8mb4_unicode_ci DEFAULT NULL,
    'primary_color' varchar(7) COLLATE utf8mb4_unicode_ci DEFAULT NULL,
    'secondary_color' varchar(7) COLLATE utf8mb4_unicode_ci DEFAULT NULL,
    'status' varchar(15) COLLATE utf8mb4_unicode_ci DEFAULT NULL,
    'quantity' bigint(20) DEFAULT NULL,
    'origin' varchar(200) COLLATE utf8mb4_unicode_ci DEFAULT NULL,
    'type' varchar(200) COLLATE utf8mb4_unicode_ci DEFAULT NULL,
    'size' varchar(200) COLLATE utf8mb4_unicode_ci DEFAULT NULL,
    'processing_time' varchar(50) COLLATE utf8mb4_unicode_ci DEFAULT NULL,
    'date_added' int(11) DEFAULT NULL,
    PRIMARY KEY ('ID')
) ENGINE=InnoDB  DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8mb4 COLLATE=utf8mb4_unicode_ci;

'relations' (
    'ID' bigint(20) unsigned NOT NULL,
    'relation_id' bigint(20) unsigned NOT NULL,
    'type' varchar(20) COLLATE utf8mb4_unicode_ci NOT NULL,
    'options' text COLLATE utf8mb4_unicode_ci,
    KEY 'ID' ('ID'),
    KEY 'relation_id' ('relation_id')
) ENGINE=InnoDB DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8mb4 COLLATE=utf8mb4_unicode_ci;

'tags' (
    'ID' bigint(20) unsigned NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
    'name' varchar(200) COLLATE utf8mb4_unicode_ci NOT NULL,
    'slug' varchar(200) COLLATE utf8mb4_unicode_ci NOT NULL,
    PRIMARY KEY ('ID')
) ENGINE=InnoDB  DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8mb4 COLLATE=utf8mb4_unicode_ci;
```

Relations between these categories goes as follows:

- products.ID = relations.ID
- relations.relation_id = tags.ID

There are 50k products, 250k relations and 25k tags added to the database for testing purposes.

I'm building a query that searches within product name, description and tags.

Executing this query:

```
Product::select('ID', 'name')->where( 'name', 'like', '%'.$search_query.'%' )->orWhere( 'description', 'like', '%'.$search_query.'%' )->orWhereHas('relations', function( $query ) use( $search_query ) {
    $query->where('type', 'tags')->whereHas('tags', function( $query ) use( $search_query ) {
        $query->where( 'name', 'like', '%'.$search_query.'%' );
    });
})->paginate(25);
```

- This query takes around 0.8s to find the data, if I query for a specific tag, it takes as long as 1.8s
- I built a similar query with joins and it took even longer so I stayed with the above query for now.

Do any of you have an idea what I might have been doing wrong? The main issue here is the query execution time.

Comment: In case you're interested, Laravel Scout https://laravel.com/docs/5.4/scout has a MySql driver https://github.com/damiantw/laravel-scout-mysql-driver.  Is there anything wrong with your query other than it takes a long time?

Comment: Thanks, I'll look into Scout. Not that I'm aware of, just the pure execution time and as we're expecting even more data, I'm worried that the execution time is going to be a problem.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There is no way to optimize this query that I know.  If you had `'LIKE', searchquery.'%'` (with no leading %) you could index the text columns for a speed boost. If you need this functionality with the wildcard on both ends, you will have to use a full-text indexing search provider.  Algolia https://www.algolia.com/ is the one I know of, and Laravel Scout is created to work with their search. This [other question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2042269/how-to-speed-up-select-like-queries-in-mysql-on-multiple-columns) also references http://sphinxsearch.com/ and http://lucene.apache.org/core/ although I don't know what they do.

Edit: also https://www.elastic.co/products/elasticsearch