MySQL like query slow with wildcards
I have a single table that contains 3.5M rows.
Such query:
select distinct 
        b.ID, 
        b.PK, 
        b.PN, 
        b.REV, 
        b.I_USE, 
        b.STATUS 
from B_DATA b 
WHERE b.PN like '________1'  

Performs in 2.8 seconds which is too slow for my case.
Running explain gives me this:

I have an index on PN column, if I run PN = 'exact_value' I see it's using an index and completes in 0.002 seconds.
I also tried to use FULLTEXT INDEX on the same column, that helps a bit with the wildcard being at the end of the value, but there is no way to use "starts with" with it.
The size of the value is either 9 or 10 characters. And also the query need to match different variations, like `A__B__CC`, or `ABCD%` or `%ABC`, etc.
Is there any way I can speed up like in these cases?

This SO answer gives a good example of how indexes work with like: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2042269/how-to-speed-up-select-like-queries-in-mysql-on-multiple-columns. Your index works, but it starts checking from the left of your string so having your character at the end makes it quite inneficient I would say...

make an index on the reverse(PN)

If you PN is hopefully indexed, if you search for A%, at least MySQL doesn't have to search pages that does not begin with A.  If each letter is in a page, that means the search is reduced to 1/26 pages.  But if your search begin with any characters, then of course it will search all 26 pages.

"...MySQL like query slow with wildcards..." -- Yep, that's how wildcards work when used as prefixes in the search pattern. Put them at the end or in the middle, but not at the beginning.

Starting a LIKE with a wildcard essentially prevents the use of an INDEX on that column.
